Issues with Installing Dependencies for AWS Lambda Layers in a Monorepo Using Lerna and Yarn Workspaces
The project that I'm working has a monorepo setup using Lerna and Yarn workspaces. Inside my monorepo, I have three applications, including a backend. Within the backend, there's a folder called layers where I place my AWS Lambda layers.
When I install dependencies and deploy using Serverless Framework (SLS), the peer dependencies of the dependencies required for the Lambda layer are not being installed.That causes lamda faliure. I verified this by creating the same Lambda layers in a different location (outside my project folder), installing the dependencies, and comparing the node_modules directories. There is a significant difference in the packages. I think that happens due to hoisting. but I don't want to get rid of the hoisting.I just need to install all the dependencies to my lambda layer.
How can I ensure that all peer dependencies are installed correctly for my AWS Lambda layers within the monorepo?
